# SQL Query with 2 Parameter in a GetRequest

Tags: java, sql, microservices

I have a question. With a GetRequest I want a SQL query where I query 2 parameters.
The Sql query is

`SELECT * FROM templates WHERE user_name=user_name AND template_id=template_id`

**User_name and template_id** should be taken over the **GetRequest**.

I want to return everything where the username is user_name and the template_id = template_id.My first try looks like this

```
public class SelectTemplate {
    public void SelectExactTemplate(String user_name, int template_id)
     {
         try{
            Connection conn=this.connect();
            Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM templates WHERE user_name=user_name AND template_id=template_id");
            while ( rs.next() ) 
            {

                rs.getString(user_name);
                rs.getInt(template_id);

            }
            conn.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
     }
     private Connection connect() {
            // SQLite connection string
            String url = "xxxxxxx";
            Connection conn = null;
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"xxxxx","xxxxxxx");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return conn;
        }
```

This is the class in which I connect to the database and start the query.
My GetRequest

```
    @GetMapping("/templates/user_name/template_id")
    public Template retrieveUser(@RequestBody Template template)
    {
        SelectTemplate app=new SelectTemplate();
        String user_name=template.getUserName();
        int template_id=template.getTemplateId();
        app.SelectExactTemplate(user_name, template_id);

        return template;
    }
```

And my Repository

```
public interface TemplateRepository extends JpaRepository<Template, Integer>{

}
```

when I start a GetRequest at POSTMAN, I get an error "**Not Found**"

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to better solve the problem?

**UPDATE**

```
    public class SelectTemplate {   
       @Autowired 
       private TemplateRepository templateRepository;
       public Template SelectExactTemplate(String user_name, int template_id) {
           return templateRepository.findByIdAndUserName(template_id, user_name);
       }
```

And the Repository

```
public interface TemplateRepository extends JpaRepository<Template, Integer>{

    Template findByIdAndUserName(int template_id, String user_name);

    Template findByUserName(String user_name);


}
```

I also tried the query once for just username. I still get the "NOT FOUND" error.

```
    @GetMapping("/templates/user_name")
    public Template retrieveTemplateByUsername(String user_name)
    {
         return templateRepository.findByUserName( user_name);  
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
@GetMapping("/templates/{user_name}")
    public List<Template> retrieveTemplateByUsername(@PathVariable("user_name") String user_name)
    {
          return templateRepository.findByUserName(user_name);  
    }
```

That works now. I had to change something in the Repository

```
List<Template> findByUserName(String user_name);
```

But if i want to find 1 template selected by template_id und user_name, i got an empty value

```
@GetMapping("/templates/{user_name}/{template_id}")
    public Template retrieveTemplate(@PathVariable("user_name") String user_name,@PathVariable("template_id") int template_id)
    {
        return templateRepository.findByIdAndUserName(template_id, user_name);

    }
```

**UPDATE 3**
Problem solved. The Query looked for the id and not for the template_id

THX A LOT

Answer (score 0):

Since you already use JPA why don't you make use of the magic `templateRepository.findByIdAndUserName`?

In that case the template service, which you called 'SelectTemplate' could contain something like:

```
@Autowired 
private TemplateRepository templateRepository;

public Template SelectExactTemplate(String user_name, int template_id) {
    return templateRepository.findByIdAndUserName(template_id, user_name);
}
```

Comment: I have now tried this in two different ways. However, I still get the error "Not Found"

Comment: Are you hitting the correct url? What is your @Get annotation?

Comment: And so I assume the Controller or the Get path is "/templates"?Could you paste those two annotations? `@Controller` `@Get` or whichever way you have them?

Comment: If i want to get all templates its @GetMapping("/templates"). And if i want to get 1 spezial template ist  @GetMapping("/templates/user_name/template_id").

I hope I understand you correctly. My english is not that good sorry

Comment: Cool, no worries. And then the @Controller has nothing else on it right?

Comment: Now i tryed this annotaion @GetMapping("/templates/{userName}") and got an success response but its empty :D

Comment: Do you have templates in the database for that username?

Comment: The exactly name is user_name in the database. But the variable in the Template class is userName

Comment: So if you put a breakpoint there on `return templateRepository.findByIdAndUserName(template_id, user_name);` in `SelectExactTemplate` and you step over the findBy execution but stop before it does the return, can you see the value found from database?

Comment: Add `@ResponseBody` in the GetMapping to look like this: ` @GetMapping("/templates/user_name")
    public @ResponseBody Template retrieveTemplateByUsername(String user_name)`

Comment: I just tried your approach. However, the same error message came. I am very grateful for your helpfulness